# empty vector<...> has no member named

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to print contents of a vector and get the following

Error message `aka class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const SoccerTeams*, std::vector<SoccerTeams> >}’ has no member named ‘teamName’`

Here's my class

```
class SoccerTeams {
    string teamName;
 public:
    vector<SoccerTeams> teams;
    void addTeam(string name) {
        SoccerTeams newTeam(name);
        teams.push_back(newTeam);
    };
    void showTeams() {
        cout << "\nHere's all the teams!";

        //error here
        for (vector<SoccerTeams>::const_iterator i = teams.begin(); i != teams.end(); ++i) 
            cout << *i.teamName << endl;
    }
    SoccerTeams(string tn){
        teamName = tn;
    };
    ~SoccerTeams(){};
};
```

I believe the error exists because the vector teams is currently empty, is there any way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The `.` operator has higher precedence than unary `*`.  So `*i.teamName` is `*(i.teamName)`, trying to look up a member `teamName` in the `const_iterator`, not the `SoccerTeams` object `*i`.

You need `(*i).teamName`, or equivalently, `i->teamName`.